# How to modify number of epochs in Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, model, training-data, epoch, transfer-learning

I'm building a model to detect cars only by using:

- The method: Tensorflow 2.0 with transfer-learning
- The pre-trained model: ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8
- The datasets: coco-2017 (with class car only)

After finish training, I run the model and get that accuracy is about 50% and total_loss scale decrease but not converging. You can check 2 pictures [detected cars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMZVy.jpg) and [tensorboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7iNc.png).

It's good to see the total_loss decrease but I can get more accuracy if the model is more converging. I have tried with num_epochs (change from 1 to 4) in pipeline.config but it doesn't work. I think it's not correct parameter to modify number of epoch for traning.

**Question:** How can I modify number of epoch for training model in Tensorflow 2.0?

You can check my file pipeline.config below.

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 1
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 320
        width: 320
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: "ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpn_keras"
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      min_depth: 16
      conv_hyperparams {
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 4e-05
          }
        }
        initializer {
          random_normal_initializer {
            mean: 0.0
            stddev: 0.01
          }
        }
        activation: RELU_6
        batch_norm {
          decay: 0.997
          scale: true
          epsilon: 0.001
        }
      }
      use_depthwise: true
      override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams: true
      fpn {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        additional_layer_depth: 128
      }
    }
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      weight_shared_convolutional_box_predictor {
        conv_hyperparams {
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 4e-05
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              mean: 0.0
              stddev: 0.01
            }
          }
          activation: RELU_6
          batch_norm {
            decay: 0.997
            scale: true
            epsilon: 0.001
          }
        }
        depth: 128
        num_layers_before_predictor: 4
        kernel_size: 3
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.6
        share_prediction_tower: true
        use_depthwise: true
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      multiscale_anchor_generator {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        anchor_scale: 4.0
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        scales_per_octave: 2
      }
    }
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-08
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
        use_static_shapes: false
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    loss {
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          gamma: 2.0
          alpha: 0.25
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 4
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_crop_image {
      min_object_covered: 0.0
      min_aspect_ratio: 0.75
      max_aspect_ratio: 3.0
      min_area: 0.75
      max_area: 1.0
      overlap_thresh: 0.0
    }
  }
  sync_replicas: true
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 0.0008
          total_steps: 50000
          warmup_learning_rate: 0.00026666
          warmup_steps: 1000
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "Tensorflow/workspace/pre-trained-models/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
  num_steps: 50000
  startup_delay_steps: 0.0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
}
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "Tensorflow/workspace/annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "Tensorflow/workspace/annotations/train.record"
  }
}
eval_config {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "Tensorflow/workspace/annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 4
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "Tensorflow/workspace/annotations/test.record"
  }
}
```

Comment: You should increase the `num_steps` if you want to train for longer. num_steps sets how many training steps you are going to use based on the batch_size. A batch_size of 100 and num_steps set to 50 will be equal to processing 5000 images in total.

Comment: @Araw Thank you for fast reply! You are correct. My teacher also explain for me about that. You can check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

My teacher said that I need to increase epoch for better result. And I was trying to find parameter for epoch but in tensorflow (without keras), I can not find it. So my teacher explain that I can modify num_steps and calculate epoch later like this:

- total images = 12000 ( images for training)
- batch_size = 4

=> 1 epoch = 12000/4 = 3000 steps

So with num_steps = 10000, I have about 3 epochs ( 10000/3000). So if I want to modify epoch, I just need to modify num_steps (total images and batch_size are fixed).